# How to get LinkedIn Professional Data using LinkedIn Rest APIs

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

I am trying to get LinkedIn Professional data via following APIs :

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,email,positions,educations)

I am passing these parameters in the API with the Access token, However I am getting the following response :

```
{
    "lastName": {
        "localized": {
            "en_US": "Mathur"
        },
        "preferredLocale": {
            "country": "US",
            "language": "en"
        }
    },
    "firstName": {
        "localized": {
            "en_US": "Salokya"
        },
        "preferredLocale": {
            "country": "US",
            "language": "en"
        }
    },
    "id": "noGMUbtiE7"
}
```

I was trying to get the professional data from LinkedIn but I am not getting the data.

Request URL : https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,email,positions,educations)

Response :

```
{
    "lastName": {
        "localized": {
            "en_US": "Mathur"
        },
        "preferredLocale": {
            "country": "US",
            "language": "en"
        }
    },
    "firstName": {
        "localized": {
            "en_US": "Salokya"
        },
        "preferredLocale": {
            "country": "US",
            "language": "en"
        }
    },
    "id": "noGMUbtiE7"
}
```

Comment: And what's your question now? If the API does not return the data you expect, why not ask the API's provider for help?